# Pass variable from one component to another one in react native

Tags: react-native

I have `ChooseLevel` component which has many buttons. Once I click a button `onLevelSelected` function is being called and it call action creator which will return an action type, moreover it will redirect me to `qPage` component. In `qPage` component I make some calculation and I put the result in total variable. 
Here's my code:

**ChooseLevel.js**

```
class ChooseLevel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    onLevelSelected(levelNumber) {
        this.props.levelSelected(levelNumber);
    }

    render(){
      <Button key={1} onPress={this.onLevelSelected.bind(this, 1)}>
      <Button key={2} onPress={this.onLevelSelected.bind(this, 2)}>
      <Button key={3} onPress={this.onLevelSelected.bind(this, 3)}>
      ....
    }
}
```

My **action creator** looks like this:

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
export const levelSelected = (levelNumber) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'level_selected', 
        payload: levelNumber
      });
      Actions.qPage();  // redirects me to qPage component 
  };
};
```

**qPage.js**

```
class qPage extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      ...
   }
   calc(){
       .... some calculation
       total = result of previous calculation 
   }
   render(){
     ....
     ....
   }
}
```

How do I pass *total* variable from qPage to ChooseLevel page?

Comment: your qpage have something to render?

Comment: yes, I omitted part of the code.

Comment: are you using redux?

Comment: yes I'm using redux

Comment: go through the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is, i will go step by step:

1) create one more action and pass calculated value inside that action.

2) access that calculated value through props(reducer)

3) You can use componentWillUpdateProp(nextprops), Inside this fuction assign this new prop to the state of the class.

Cheers :)

Comment: Ok, I've followed the steps. Now inside mapStateToProps function (which is in ChooseLevel.js file) I can correctly console.log total's value and If I print it inside render() method I can successfully see it. My problem now is that I tried to console.log(this.props.total) inside componentWillReceiveProps() but it returns me undefined